# Error: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexImage2D

Tags: three.js, webgl, textures, shader

We are developing a kind of 3D graph. We are using Angular with Three-full NPM (https://github.com/Itee/three-full).  We are implementing the Nodes as particles and we are drawing them with shaders.

Code bellow of the post*

That works pretty good in the web browser (Mozilla and Chromium) with Linux environment but when we test it in the web browser with Windows environment, shaders crash and the drawing of the nodes is not done (appear that error message).

[image]

*Error Message in Windows environment*

[image]

*3D Graph in Linux environment*

[image]

*3D Graph in Windows environment*

We search what the error means but there’s no clarifying information. The point is that if we use LineMaterial and not Shaders with RawShadersMaterial  then it works nice, but with a reduction in performance. Is there any technical issue in Windows System that make it happens? How we can solve it? We try to comment everything about textures but it generate the same error. It seems that the problem in relate especially with the use of both Shaders.

Code running, example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmartmilln/a48by2vr/

```
const particles = this.numNodesValue;

    if (particles > 0) {

      const particle_system_geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

      // Buffers
      const positionBuffer = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(particles * 12)); // For positioning
      const colorBuffer = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(particles * 3)); // For giving color to nodes
      const sizeBuffer = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(particles * 4)); // For giving size to nodes
      const highlightBuffer = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(particles * 4)); // For giving highlight
      const subjectsBuffer = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(particles * 4)); // For subjects
      const selectedBuffer = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(particles * 4)); // For selected

      this.radius = Math.min(1000, Math.max(100, Math.sqrt(particles * Math.PI * 20)));

      this.innerDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.radius - this.camera.position.x, 2) +
        Math.pow(0 - this.camera.position.y, 2) + Math.pow(0 - this.camera.position.z, 2));

      const dispersion = this.radiusDispersion;

      for (let i = 0; i < particles; i++) {

        let particularDispersion = 0;

        if (dispersion > 0) {
          particularDispersion = (((Math.ceil(Math.random() * 11) - 1) / 10) * dispersion) + Math.random(); // [0..1] * dispersion
        }

        highlightBuffer[i] = 1.0;

        const angleX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * Math.PI;
        const angleY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * Math.PI;

        const posX = (this.radius + particularDispersion) * Math.sin(angleX) * Math.cos(angleY);
        const posY = (this.radius + particularDispersion) * Math.sin(angleX) * Math.sin(angleY);
        const posZ = (this.radius + particularDispersion) * Math.cos(angleX);

        positionBuffer[(i * 3)]     = posX;
        positionBuffer[(i * 3) + 1] = posY;
        positionBuffer[(i * 3) + 2] = posZ;

        colorBuffer[(i * 3)]     = (Math.random() * 255);
        colorBuffer[(i * 3) + 1] = (Math.random() * 255);
        colorBuffer[(i * 3) + 2] = (Math.random() * 255);

        subjectsBuffer[i] = Math.random() < 0.3 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        selectedBuffer[i] = 0.0;

        if (particularDispersion !== 0) {
          sizeBuffer[i] = Math.floor((Math.pow(particularDispersion, 2) / Math.pow(dispersion, 2)) * this.sizeDiff);
        } else {
          sizeBuffer[i] = 0;
        }
      }

      const nodeBufferPosition  = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(positionBuffer, 3);
      const nodeBufferColor     = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(colorBuffer, 3);
      const nodeBufferSize      = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(sizeBuffer, 1);
      const nodeBufferHighlight = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(highlightBuffer, 1);
      const nodeBufferSubject   = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(subjectsBuffer, 1);
      const nodeBufferSelected  = new THREE.InterleavedBuffer(selectedBuffer, 1);

      particle_system_geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(nodeBufferPosition, 3, 0, false));
      particle_system_geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(nodeBufferColor, 3, 0, true));
      particle_system_geometry.addAttribute('size', new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(nodeBufferSize, 4, 0, true));
      particle_system_geometry.addAttribute('highlighted', new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(nodeBufferHighlight, 4, 0, true));
      particle_system_geometry.addAttribute('subject', new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(nodeBufferSubject, 4, 0, true));
      particle_system_geometry.addAttribute('selected', new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(nodeBufferSelected, 4, 0, true));

      const vertexShader = [
        'precision highp float;',
        '',
        'uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;',
        'uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;',
        '',
        'attribute vec3 position;',
        'attribute vec3 color;',
        'attribute float size;',
        'attribute float highlighted;',
        'attribute float subject;',
        'attribute float selected;',
        '',
        'varying vec3 vColor;',
        'varying float vHighlighted;',
        'varying float vSubject;',
        'varying float vSelected;',
        '',
        'void main() {',
        '',
        ' vColor = color;',
        ' vHighlighted = highlighted;',
        ' vSubject = subject;',
        ' vSelected = selected;',
        '   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.xyz , 1.0);',
        '',
        ' if (subject > 0.0) {',
        '',
        '     gl_PointSize = (10.0 + (size * 2.0)) * (300.0 / length(gl_Position.xyz));',
        '',
        ' } else {',
        '',
        '   gl_PointSize = (15.0 + (size * 2.0)) * (300.0 / length(gl_Position.xyz));',
        '',
        ' }',
        '',
        '}'
      ].join('\n');
      const fragmentShader = [
        'precision highp float;',
        '',
        'uniform sampler2D map;',
        'uniform sampler2D map2;',
        'uniform sampler2D mapSelected;',
        '',
        'varying vec3 vColor;',
        'varying float vHighlighted;',
        'varying float vSubject;',
        'varying float vSelected;',
        '',
        'void main() {',
        '',
        ' vec2 uv = vec2(gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y);',
        '',
        ' if (vSelected > 0.0) {',
        '',
        '   vec4 textureColor = vec4(texture2D(mapSelected, uv));',
        '   gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor * vec4(vColor, 1.0));',
        '',
        ' } else {',
        '   if (vSubject > 0.0) {',
        '',
        '     vec4 textureColor = vec4(texture2D(map2, uv));',
        '     gl_FragColor = vec4((vec3(1) - textureColor.rgb) * vColor, textureColor.a);',
        '',
        '   } else {',
        '',
        '       gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(map, uv) * vec4(vColor, 1.0));',
        '',
        '     if (vHighlighted == 0.0) {',
        '       gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, gl_FragColor.a);',
        '     }',
        '',
        '     if (gl_FragColor.a > 0.6) gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;',
        '',
        '   }',
        ' }',
        '',
        ' if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.6) discard;',
        '',
        '}'
      ].join('\n');

      const uniforms = {
        map: { type: 't', value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('../../assets/transparent_sphere.png')},
        map2: { type: 't', value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('../../assets/reach.svg')},
        mapSelected: { type: 't', value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('../../assets/Design1.png')},
      };

      const nodeMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
        defines: {
          USE_MAP: true
        },
        transparent: true
      });

      particle_system_geometry.boundingBox = null;
      particle_system_geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

      this.mesh = new THREE.Points( particle_system_geometry, nodeMaterial );

      this.scene.add( this.mesh );
}
```